# Obtaining object id in core data

Tags: swift, core-data, primary-key, nsmanagedobject

I am currently practicing with Swift and Core Data, making an app with a login. When i fetch data from my users entity i receive this:

```
[<NSManagedObject: 0x7f8f1300c640> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000380000 <x-coredata://E67F6A37-4E56-4A55-A01E-940D8BD9EBE9/Users/p14> ; data: {
password = password;
userName = user;})]
```

Is there a way to obtain de id 0xd000000000380000? I am new using core data and i have only used SQL. I know Core data is not a DB but i think that id is like a primary key, isn't it?

I want to obtain that to use it to find an object of an entity.

Answer (score 0):

The unique identifier is actually represented by `x-coredata://E67F6A37-4E56-4A55-A01E-940D8BD9EBE9/Users/p14`.

See the [`NSManagedObject -objectID`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSManagedObject/objectID) method for details.